# Elasticsearch geo-location search not returning results for miles unit

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, geolocation, location-services

im using elasticsearch to return business near a users location.

If i search with a distance unit of kilometer 'km' i get expected results but if i use miles 'm' it return 0 hits

example of km request with hits

```
{
  "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "km"
          }
      }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "1km",
                "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

1km = 0.6 miles so this query should return the same number of results as above but returns 0

```
{
  "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "m"
          }
      }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "1m",
                "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: `m` is meter, miles is `mi` ([more info about distance units](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#distance-units))

Comment: you are correct if you put it in a answer i will mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use the [correct distance unit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#distance-units): `m` is for meters, and for miles you need to use `mi`

```
{
  "sort" : [
      {
          "_geo_distance" : {
              "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
              }, 
              "order" : "asc",
              "unit" : "mi"                     <--- here
          }
      }
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "1mi",             <--- here
                "location" : {
                    "lon": -0.11454850000000001,
                    "lat": 51.4911665
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```